# What is different in enumarating NSDictionary directly in compare to enumerating its allValues?

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to understand/learn Objective-C. I am lost what is the difference between enumerating

```
for (TypeOfValuesInDictionary *item in dictionary) {}
```

and enumerating

```
for (TypeOfValuesInDictionary *item in [dictionary allValues]) {}
```

?

The former tends to return less values from the dictionary than the latter but I failed to find/understand why? Documentation nor web search gave me the necessary insight/answer.

Comment: Can you add an example, when the second one "returns" less values.

Comment: `for (TypeOf*KEYS*InDictionary *item in dictionary) {}` That's what it really do.

Comment: Strange, it seemed to partially work (a higher intention I was trying to achieve with this part of code) even with the TypeOfValues in the for cycle as well as when I used that objects inside the cycle. I will recheck tomorrow what was really there. The dictionary is provided by a third-party.

Answer (score 0):

The first one iterates over the keys, not the values.

F'up: What's the difference to iterating over the array of keys?

A: It is less efficient.